# Java Graphics2D: semi-transparency turns black when using blur filter on shape

Tags: java, filter, blur, graphics2d

I'm using Java Graphics2D and JH Labs' gaussian filter to blur some shapes I've drawn in a transparent image. I notice that the blurred border of the shape turns black, more like a drop shadow. Instead, it should just be gradually more transparent, letting the background color shine through.

[image]

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();

// Draw shape
g2d.fillRect(x, y, shapeWidth, shapeHeight);

// Apply gaussian filter
BufferedImage bi2 = new BufferedImage(imgWidth, imgHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
GaussianFilter gaussianFilter = new GaussianFilter();
gaussianFilter.setRadius(10.0f);
gaussianFilter.filter(bi, bi2);
bi = bi2;
```

Any idea where the black comes from and, more importantly, how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether the question is still relevant or not. I came across an article about blurring, especially when alpha channels are involved, and the author described exactly the phenomenon you mentioned in your question. Here's what the author wrote:

> The reason is that we've blurred each channel separately, but where
>   the alpha channel is zero (the transparent bits), the red, green and
>   blue channels are zero, or black. When you do the blur, the black gets
>   mixed in with the opaque bits and you get a dark shadow. The solution
>   is to premultiply the image alpha before blurring and unpremultiply it
>   afterwards. Of course, if your images are already premultiplied,
>   you're all set.

You may have a look at http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html for more information.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Neckelatius,
Unfortunately the question isn't relevant anymore, but thanks a lot for answering anyway! It sounds like a very plausible explanation. I'll definitely keep this in mind if I stumble upon similar problems again.